# Printing list to file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[u'first              ', u'second         ']
```

I want to have a file that looks like this:

```
first    second
```

File entries in each line should be tab delimited. Here is what I did:

```
with open ('output','wb') as f1:
    f1.write('COLUMN1'+'\t'+'COLUMN2'+'\n')
        for element in mylist:
            f1.write(element+'\t')
        f1.write('\n')
```

The file looks OK when I open it. However, when I open it in Pandas:

```
tmp=pd.read_csv('output',delimiter='\t')
print tmp.head()
```

everything is messed up:

```
                              COLUMN1                      COLUMN2
0  first                       second                         NaN
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using csv writer for making the csv. For example:

```
header = ['COLUMN1', 'COLUMN2']

mylist =  [[u'first              ', u'second         '],
           [u'val1              ', u'val2         ']]

with open('out.csv', 'wb') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')

    csvwriter.writerow(header)
    for row in mylist:
        csvwriter.writerow([c.strip() for c in row])


import pandas as pd

tmp = pd.read_csv('out.csv', delimiter='\t')
```

print(tmp)

This results in:

```
  COLUMN1 COLUMN2
0   first  second
1    val1    val2
```

And if you dont want to use csv, just do this:

```
with open ('out.csv','w') as f1:
    f1.write('COLUMN1'+'\t'+'COLUMN2'+'\n')
    for row in mylist:
        f1.write("\t".join(v.strip() for v in row) + "\n")
```

Comment: No, I am still getting the same result with my file. My list is a stream of lists I am processing one list at a time and writing it into a file (if this helps). It's not a file that contains list of lists.

Comment: So can you provide example of your file? This starts to be a guessing game at this point.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Your anwser does not suggest using csv module. Dont know how you can claim "this is basically what I have already suggested in my answer"?

Comment: I already suggested stripping and the OP said it did not work so how would using the csv module be any different?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham For starters using csv module to work with csv files is better than reinventing a wheel, and making mistakes as OP is clearly doing.

Comment: where is the csv file?

Comment: In case you haven't read the OP question, `tmp=pd.read_csv()`.

Comment: OP expects to write and then read a csv file. Extensions is not important.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Using the csv module will properly quote values which contain tabs. So Marcin's method would work in a situation where neither of our solutions do.

Comment: @unutbu, yes but for the given example calling the file output.foobar and using any method should work so using the csv module or not has no relevance.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Given that the OP says `rstrip`ping the tabs did not work, we have to assume there is something different in his *real* problem than the simplified form he posted in the question.

Comment: @unutbu, I am pretty sure he is a she.

Comment: I prefer to think everyone on the net is a bot :)

Comment: the file is exactly as I wrote the question. The only thing I can add is that each entry is 35 characters. If the string is less than 32 char, it is padded with spaces.

Comment: And the second code prints all characters separated with a space

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! I had an additional loop within my code to stream my input and I made a mistake when I paste this code. Everything works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values in the columns do not themselves contain spaces, you could use `\s+` to make *1-or-more whitespace* the regex pattern for the delimiter between columns:

```
In [87]: pd.read_table('output', delimiter=r'\s+')
Out[87]: 
  COLUMN1 COLUMN2
0   first  second
```

Thus, no change to the way `output` is created may be necessary.

Comment: the OP is creating output not changing it

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: The OP wanted to change output because he thinks it is necessary to allow pandas to parse it into a proper DataFrame. The above shows that that is not necessary.

Comment: either way, creating output as a tab delimited file should work no?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Yes, for sure. In fact, I overstated things by claiming `\s+` will work. It may not work if the values in the columns themselves contain spaces.